# Cassandra timestamp Sort order

Tags: database, sorting, cassandra

I have a Cassandra table with `clustering` by `timestamp` sorted ascending and am doing queries of events in the last 24 hours. I'd like the result set to be sorted by 24 hours ago first with the data first (which is why the column was sorted by `timestamp` ascending), but am wondering if there are any performance impacts I'm missing since I am always querying by the most recent data, and any timeseries posts I see always suggest sorting by `timestamp` `desc`.

Answer (score 0):

I would not supposed that. The key order by specified during table creation just helps to set a default sort order.

Cassandra is smart enough to sort in any direction during query execution based on input